# German RepRep Neo can't heat the extruder

Tags: extruder, heat-management

The printer stopped heating the extruder in the middle of the print and I noticed it getting cooled down. After a few seconds, I heard a ticking noise near the filament (which could probably mean the filament was being pushed into a cold extruder and was skipping. Now, when I try to heat the extruder, it won't heat up. What could've gone broken?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first, check the breakers 
[image]
[pic source](https://www.germanreprap.com/myfactory/web/cms/produkt/100279.aspx)

### secondary stuff

please see a list of item to check, that could point you to the source:

1. heater cable cut/melted/loose => the best way will be to check the resistance (it shall be around 3.3 Ohms) from the heater cable terminals on the mainboard, if that fails it could be a wire on heater itself.
2. with the heating switch on - measure the voltage on terminals - shall be 12V, if not  - that  could suggest a mainboard failure or mosfet failure (in case of mosfet you could measure if there is an input signal given on the middle pin)
3. there also could be a breaker that was engaged due to short circuit on the wires (the main board layout is not known to me and it is not clear form manual I found online)